# Mongodb stuck at version 5

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have been running a mongodb version 4 for a while on my amazon ec2 with amazon linux 2013. I have then successfully updated MongoDB to version 5 by following the documentation:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/
By adding the repo file, sudo yum update will automatically update MongoDB.

I then did the same with MongoDB 6:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon/

I added a repo file etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-6.0.repo with the content

```
[mongodb-org-6.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/6.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc
```

I then run

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```

But I get

```
amzn-main                                                                                                       | 2.1 kB  00:00:00     
amzn-updates                                                                                                    | 3.8 kB  00:00:00     
mongodb-org-3.4                                                                                                 | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
mongodb-org-3.6                                                                                                 | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
mongodb-org-4.0                                                                                                 | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
mongodb-org-4.2                                                                                                 | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
mongodb-org-4.4                                                                                                 | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
mongodb-org-5.0                                                                                                 | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
mongodb-org-6.0                                                                                                 | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
Package mongodb-org-5.0.15-1.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

What could be the reason it doesn't find any version 6 of MongoDB and thinks version 5 is the latest?

I also see the same issue if I try to force install version 6:

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org-6.0.4 mongodb-org-database-6.0.4 mongodb-org-server-6.0.4 mongodb-org-mongos-6.0.4 mongodb-org-tools-6.0.4
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Repository mongodb-org-3.6 is listed more than once in the configuration
amzn-main                                                                                                       | 2.1 kB  00:00:00     
amzn-updates                                                                                                    | 3.8 kB  00:00:00     
No package mongodb-org-6.0.4 available.
No package mongodb-org-database-6.0.4 available.
No package mongodb-org-server-6.0.4 available.
No package mongodb-org-mongos-6.0.4 available.
No package mongodb-org-tools-6.0.4 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: you should provide much more details and description

Comment: What answer you expect to a question "I did everything like in the docs but it doesn't work" ? Please include exact steps you did with exact commands. And add a link to "the docs" you were following. You must have missed something, but there is no way to tell unless you describe what you did exactly

Comment: Rephrased the question with more details. Hope this will help to better find an answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't host v6 there at the time of answering. If you open the url now it's only mongosh and db tools there.

Must be a rare case when documentation is not up-to-date, but ahead-the-date =)

If you feel adventurous, you can try a release candidate v6.0.0.rc1 from testing repo:

```
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/amazon/2013.03/mongodb-org/testing/x86_64/
```